# Why this logging PHP script always sais "wrong password"?

Tags: php, mysql

I made a script to admin login on website. I configured MySQL database correctly, but this PHP script always sais "Wrong password" and don't redirect. Can you help me? I DB login is TEXT and password is VARCHAR 255. I thougth that password sha512 encryption was a problem, so I deleted it. No effect.
Code:

```
error_reporting(0);
  $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "*******", "******") or die("Server connection error");
  mysql_select_db("******", $connection) or die("Database connection error");
  if ($_POST['Login']){
    if ($_POST['nick'] && $_POST['haslo']){
      $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nick']);
      $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));
      $user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `login`='$username'"));
      if ($user == '0') {
        die("Login failed: Wrong username!");
      }
      $pass = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `Password` FROM `users` WHERE `Password`='$password'"));
      if ($pass == '0'){
        die("Login failed: Wrong password!");
      }
      setcookie("c_user", $username, time() + 1 * 60 * 60, "/");
      header('Location: panel.php');
    }
  }
```

Comment: You shouldn't tell the user wrong password.. It gives other people too much information a user exists..

Comment: Do you have some secial chars in you password like $ , if so you must escape it with \$

Comment: Logical flaw with doing those two separate queries.... if I did enter a valid username and a valid password, logically it would log me in __even if the password was a password for a completely different user__.... retrieve username and password in a single query; and don't store passwords in plaintext

Comment: Do a `var_export($user);` after you fetch it and you'll get your answer.

Comment: As noted by others, there are numerous security issues that would justify replacing this with an existing script written by someone who cares about your security more than you do.

Comment: Are you encrypting the passwords?